# How to get Facebook Session with Parse v1.9.0 Facebook Signup

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am integrating `Parse.com 1.9.0` sdk with `ParseFacebookUtilsv4-1.9.0` for Facebook integration in my app.
Earlier `ParseFacebookUtils.getSession()` used to give Facebook session but in this updated sdk there is no `getSession()` method available.

How do I get the Facebook session to call Facebook requests?

Comment: I have having the same issue. They've also broken finishAuthentication, but a similar looking method seems to be onActivityResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested yet (debugging the crap out of my own app facing these upgrade issues), but this should work: Try Facebook API 4.0's `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()`. Will confirm if this works by editing answer at earliest.

Check this out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

Comment: AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() gives the corrrect token. Parse.com documents should be updated.